# Open GL - ES 2.0 : Multiple Vertex Buffer Object

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I had a quick question on openGL ES 2.0 I am trying to create some drawings on the screen which will require multiple geometries. This is how I am creating the geometries.

```
(void)setupBoxGeometry{

   GLuint vertexBuffer;
   glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(BoxVertices), BoxVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

   GLuint indexBuffer;
   glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
   glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(BoxIndices), BoxIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

- (void)setupLineGeometry{

   GLuint vertexBuffer;
   glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(LineVertices), LineVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

   GLuint indexBuffer;
   glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
   glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(LineIndices), LineIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

This is my render function

```
- (void)render:(CADisplayLink*)displayLink {
   glClearColor(0.0/255.0, 0.0/255.0, 0.0/255.0, 1.0);
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   float h = 4.0f * self.frame.size.height / self.frame.size.width;
   glViewport(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

   glVertexAttribPointer(_positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 
                      sizeof(Vertex), 0);
   glVertexAttribPointer(_colorSlot, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 
                      sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) (sizeof(float) * 3));


   // Do some thing to the projection    
   CC3GLMatrix *projection = [CC3GLMatrix matrix];    
   [projection populateFromFrustumLeft:-2 andRight:2 andBottom:-h/2 andTop:h/2 andNear:4 andFar:10];
   glUniformMatrix4fv(_projectionUniform, 1, 0, projection.glMatrix);


   // Create the base for the square to be drawn on the screen    
   _baseMatrix = [CC3GLMatrix matrix];


   [_baseMatrix populateFromTranslation:CC3VectorMake(-3.0, -5.2 + _yIncrease, -10)];    
   [_baseMatrix scaleByX:0.5];
   [_baseMatrix scaleByY:_yIncrease];
   [_baseMatrix rotateBy:CC3VectorMake(0, _rotationAngle, 0)];
   glUniformMatrix4fv(_modelViewUniform, 1, 0, _baseMatrix.glMatrix);
   glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(BoxIndices)/sizeof(BoxIndices[0]), 
               GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
}
```

I call the box geometry function before I call the line geometry function. The problem is now my render function only draws lines. It does not draw any boxes. What am I doing wrong. If the question is not clear I can give more clarifications/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you binding buffers before drawing?
Call

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
```

before

```
glVertexAttribPointer(...);
```

And call

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
```

before

```
glDrawElements(...);
```

Also you need to enable vertex pointers you are using:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_positionSlot);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_colorSlot);
```

Comment: I realized in opengl es there is only 1 vertex buffer possible. All the points that are required by all the geometries have to be stored in 1 single vertex buffer. use the index buffer to index appropriately into the vertex buffer

Comment: No, different components of vertices (like colors, normals, positions, etc...) can be stored in different vertex buffers. When you call glVertexAttribPointer, then it takes offset (last argument) in currently bound buffer. After glVertexAttribPointer call you can bind different buffer and specify pointer in it.